# platform independent c++ DLL

Tags: c++, ios, dll

I had writin one dll in c++ that runs perfectly on c# apps.
it's something like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "fun.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)double Add(double a, double b,double k);
extern double Add(double a, double b,double k) 
{ 
    return a+b+k;
}
```

Now i want to run this same DLL on MAC apps..what changes i need to have in my current DLL?

Comment: you can not write platform independent dlls. They depend on the architecture (x86 or x64) and only work on windows. On linux you have .so and on mac you have .dylib as shared libraries.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with other platforms. The language is the same but libraries and compilers are often different. So the whole compiling process would also be different. The amount of work depends on the size and the libraries you are using in your DLL.

Comment: How are you going to run the C# app on the Mac? If not, then who would use your library?

Comment: m not going to run C# app on MAC..will have differnt MAC app with same bussines logic

Comment: For better or for worse (worse, IMHO), DLL has taken on a more generic meaning, and I regularly hear `.so` files under Unix called DLL's.  And you can certainly _write_ code which works on a variety of plaforms.  (We have a number of "DLLs" which work on both Windows and Linux, loaded from Python or Java.)

Comment: And of course, `"stdafx.h"` is also Windows specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a DLL that loads on both Windows and Mac. You will need to re-compile your code for Mac.

Comment: You need either a cross compiler if you're using a different development platform, or compile it in an appropriate MAC development environment.

Comment: but <b>extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)</b> is entirely for windows based apps..???..how can MAC app will fetch data from C++ dll...like for c# we have __declspec(dllimport) to import data from DLL

Comment: @james On most systems, you don't need any extra baggage to make something accessible from a DLL.  I'd stick with the `extern "C"', but I'd put the `__declspec(dllexport)' in a conditionally defined macro, which is defined to nothing on platforms other than Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run any dll on mac. Mac has it's own dynamic loaded library.

Comment: And what do you thing "dll" means, if not "dynamically loaded library".  It's a bad choice of vocabulary, since the results don't behave like a library, but more like a single object.  But that's a battle I've given up on---everyone calls them DLLs, even under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using c# I believe you have 2 options. The first option is to see if your code will run in mono on the mac. For that you will create macintosh executables and dynamic libraries.

http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX

http://lipsky.me/2012/7/21/calling-a-dynamic-library-from-monomac-part-1

The second is to use .NET 2.0 or lower and see if your application will run under wine on the macintosh. Do not use any .NET 3.X or greater in your code since .NET 3.X or greater will not install or have a lot of problems in wine.

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3754